# Allow cy.wait to fail

Tags: cypress, end-to-end

After reading a lot of docs and try to find a solution to my problem I didn't find anything, so here we go.

I have the following problem testing my end to end flow, the flow I'm testing does launch requests continuously but in one case I expect these requests to stop. In other words, I want to throw an error if the request is made and continue with errors when hits the timeout without any request.

```
cy.wait('@my-request', { timeout: 20000 })
```

I expect this to timeout if the app works fine so I tried to do this.

```
cy.wait('@my-request', { timeout: 20000 })
    .its('status').should('not.eq', 404)
    .its('status').should('not.eq', 200);
```

I expected to execute the chained tasks but this only happens when the request is made, as well as tried to use a `.then` but I have the same problem.

Comment: not sure what are you trying to do but cy.wait() only accepts aliases for routes and it seems you're trying to do for request ?

Comment: At one point in the flow, the app should stop pooling an API and I want to test this and fail the test if any new occurrence of this endpoint is called.

Comment: ok, I guess you're trying to do request polling, see that link https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Request-Polling

Comment: Request doesn't match my requirements. I found a workaround with ```ci.on('fail')```

Comment: nice one!, please mark your comments below as an answer, it will help community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a global on fail event can help us but also limits to not execute additional code when this test is failing and we force it to be marked as done.

In the test definition we can add the done callback like in the example.

```
it('Description', (done) => {
// other test stuff
cy.on('fail', (err) => {
    if (err.name === 'CypressError' && err.message.includes('routeAlias') && err.message.includes('Timed out')) {
        done();
        return true;
    }
    throw err;
});
cy.wait('@routeAlias', { timeout: 20000 })
    .then(() => {
        throw new Error('Error request found.');
    });
});
// Any remaining code won't be executed if you need to reset something you need to create a new step, like in my case I did a new step to click a cancel button and prepare the app for the next test.
```

Now our test passes when this specific error is caught but any other error will lead to a test error.

This kind of workarounds are not recommended by cypress but unless cypress adds a catch to manage some errors it's the only way to fix my problem.